# Python: cannot get href from webdiver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<td>
  <div class="buy_car_list_img">
    <a href="buy_detail.aspx?TSEQNO=5002081">
      <img src="http://www.xxxxx.com//UPLOAD/AM/BF5054/26531.jpg" width="100">
    </a>
  </div>
</td>
```

I want to get href's url.

```
buy_detail.aspx?TSEQNO=5002081
```

Code:

```
g=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("buy_car_list_img")
#print(g)
for item in g:
    print(item.get_attribute('href'))
```

When I printed this, it returned "none", any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `class` is on the div which does not have an `href` attribute. You want to get the `a` tag. Try [find_elements_by_css_selector](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector)

```
g = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.buy_car_list_img a')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modified your xpath, like this. You need to pass `<a>` tag in xpath. Right now you are trying to point class name and try to prinr href which is not there. So need to locate anchor tag which have href and then try to print

```
g=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='buy_car_list_img']//a")
#print(g)

for item in g:
    print(item.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks Please accept as answer by clicking right below downvote